# Lambda duration > 10x longer than expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In the below example, I have an AWS Lambda function (written in Node) where the business logic is executed in 60ms, yet the full duration is 794ms.

```
23:49:19 START RequestId: d1110932-2586-11e8-8d80-f74f5d6cf7b8 Version: $LATEST
23:49:20 2018-03-11T23:49:20.559Z   d1110932-2586-11e8-8d80-f74f5d6cf7b8    Start of Lambda: 1520812160559
...
23:49:20 2018-03-11T23:49:20.619Z   d1110932-2586-11e8-8d80-f74f5d6cf7b8    End of Lambda 1520812160619
23:49:20 END RequestId: d1110932-2586-11e8-8d80-f74f5d6cf7b8
23:49:20 REPORT RequestId: d1110932-2586-11e8-8d80-f74f5d6cf7b8 Duration: 794.57 ms Billed Duration: 800 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 52 MB
```

I'm confused as to why the function is taking so long to execute given that everything inside the handler executes in 60ms.

Some notes:

- `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` is set to `false`
- In this example the container was being reused from a previous execution.
- Duration appears to be highly variable. Sometimes it is <100ms, sometimes >1s.

Is there any way to investigate / reduce this duration? Is it common to see so much of a Lambda's execution attributed to startup time, even on subsequent executions?

**Relevant code:**

```
export const getPublishedLessons = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // establish inside of handler to avoid extra db connections
  const lessonService = new LessonService()
  try {
    const results = await lessonService.getLessonsByFilter({ isPublished: true })
    console.error('End of Lambda', moment().valueOf())
    return respond(callback, results)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(`Error in lessonHandler.getManyLessons: [${err}]`)
    return fail(callback, err)
  }
}


const eventWrapper = async (event, context, callback, eventFunction) => {
  console.error('Start of Lambda: ', moment().valueOf())
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
  if(event.source === 'serverless-plugin-warmup') {
    // ensure db connection
    await mongoFactory.getConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI, process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME)
    const mongoService = new MongoService()
    await mongoService.createIndexes('Lessons', [ _idIndex, lessonIdIndex ], indexOptions)
    await mongoService.createIndexes('LessonThemes', [ _idIndex ], indexOptions)
    await mongoService.createIndexes('LessonMetadata', [ typeIndex ], indexOptions)
    await mongoService.createIndexes('Messages', [ _idIndex ], indexOptions)
    await mongoService.createIndexes('PasswordRecovery', [ _idIndex ], indexOptions)
    await mongoService.createIndexes('Profiles', [ _idIndex ], indexOptions)
    await mongoService.createIndexes('UserLessons', [ _idIndex, lessonIdIndex, userIdIndex ], indexOptions)
    await mongoService.createIndexes('UserProjects', [ _idIndex, userIdIndex ], indexOptions)
    console.log('WarmUP - Lambda is warm!')
    return callback(null, 'Lambda is warm!')
  }
  if(event.body && isString(event.body))
    event.body = JSON.parse(event.body)
  return await eventFunction(event, context, callback)
}

module.exports.getPublishedLessonsHandler = (...params) => eventWrapper(...params, getPublishedLessons)
```

Comment: I think we need the function code here

Comment: thanks - added it in.

Comment: lambda does serialization/deserialization. Is your request or response huge?

Comment: 31.3KB in this case for the response. The request is a GET request with the largest header being a JWT token.

Comment: Strategically logging the value returned by `context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()` may be informative.  If it isn't initially near the max, then that's time spent before you first were able to log it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm seeing as much as 170ms of lost time by logging `context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()` at the start of my lambda. Not sure what to do about it unfortunately.

Comment: Add something like `const container_startup = (new Date).toISOString();` to the beginning of your file, outside any functions.  Log that value early in your handler.  During the first invocation using the container, the difference between this and the current timestamps is your own code's initialization time, and any further missing time is time for the service to get the container ready (from my observations).  This also gives you a better perspective of container reuse and lifetimes.

Comment: I'm not seeing a large internal initialization time in my Lambda using this logging method. I will keep this question open for now, but this is starting to feel like a RAM configuration issue based the log statements and this reading: https://serverless.com/blog/aws-lambda-power-tuning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question based on information found [here](https://dashbird.io/blog/optimizing-aws-lambda-for-production/):

My Lambda's RAM was configured to 128mb and my execution times were anywhere from ~100ms to ~1s, even with a reused container.

After increasing RAM to 1536mb, my execution times are consistently well under 100ms. 1536mb is obviously much more expensive per millisecond, but I expect that my overall price won't increase dramatically given the reduced execution time.